# Large dropdown menus (off expected location)

Tags: macos, google-chrome, ui

I have a problem with dropdown menus appearing in really large size, in a wrong location to where it should be on screen (namely below and to the right of the expected location). I have experienced this for over a month on various websites, producing the same result.

[image: clicking the button marked with a red circle, opens the dropdown in the shown size and location]
[the shown website](http://hiking-biking-slovenia.com/hiking/en/)

I experience this in Chrome on my Macbook Pro 15" and have tested with all extensions deactivated with the same results.

Anybody have an idea of what is going on or what could solve it?

Chrome Version 57.0.2987.133 (Official Build) (64-bit),
macOS: Sierra 10.12.4 (16E195),
MacBook Pro: Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015

Comment: Have you tested the same website using another browser (e.g. Safari, Firefox, etc)? Also, are you certain it's been over a month? I'm just wondering if it's some sort of bug (or incompatibility) between Chrome version 57.0.2987.133 and macOS Sierra 10.12.4 (especially since they're both only about 3 weeks old).

Comment: No, it could well be within the last three weeks.
Just tested on Firefox (52.0.2 (64-bit)) and Safari (Version 10.1 (12603.1.30.0.34)) and the dropdown appear correctly in both.

Comment: It must be a bug in Google Chrome or a compatibility issue between Google Chrome and macOS Sierra 10.12.4. Since Safari uses the WebKit engine and Firefox uses the Gecko engine to render web pages, and they each work okay, I'd suggest you send feedback via the Help > Report an issue option. Also, I tested Chrome visiting the hiking-biking page you reference and it worked fine in El Capitan but not Sierra.

Comment: @Monomeeth Please add this as an official answer, then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Google Chrome **or** a compatibility issue between Google Chrome and macOS Sierra 10.12.4.

Safari uses the WebKit engine and Firefox uses the Gecko engine to render web pages, and I've tested each and they load the hiking-biking page you reference just fine in macOS Sierra 10.12.4.

I also tested Chrome visiting the same page and it worked fine in El Capitan but not macOS Sierra 10.12.4.

I'd suggest you send feedback via the **Help > Report an issue** option.